# What positive distribution has the form $x^{-\ln(x)}$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, continuous-variables

What is the name for the continuous distribution $f(x)\propto x^{-\ln(x)}$ for $x\geq 0$? More precisely, I'd like the name for the family of distributions of the form $f(x)\propto x^{-c \ln(x)}$, where $c$ is a positive constant.

As for the significance of this distribution, it's the simplest one that dies (approaches 0) at a super-polynomial and sub-exponential rate both as $x\to\infty$ and $x\to 0$. Also, fwiw, the normalizing constant for the distribution has a simple closed form: $$\sqrt{\frac{e^{c/2} \pi}{c}}$$

Comment: $x^{-\log x} = e^{-\log^2 x}$ so you might explore a generalized lognormal.

Answer (score 1):

like in [Does the distribution whose pdf is proportional to $\exp(-\log^2(x))$ have a name?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4460047/does-the-distribution-whose-pdf-is-proportional-to-exp-log2x-have-a-nam/4460796#4460796),

\begin{align}
x^{-\log x} &=
\exp(-\log^2 x) \\
&\propto \exp(-\log^2 x)/\exp(0.25) \\
&= \exp(-\log^2 x - 0.25) \\
&= \exp(-(\log^2 x + 0.25)) \\
&= \exp(-(\log^2 x + 0.25 - \log x + \log x)) \\
&= \exp(-((\log^2 x - 0.5)^2 + \log x)) \\
&= \exp(-(\log^2 x - 0.5)^2 - \log x) \\
&= \exp(-(\log^2 x - 0.5)^2)/x \\
&propto \exp(-(\log^2 x - 0.5)^2)/x/\sqrt\pi \\
\end{align}
This is a log-normal with $\mu=0.5$ and $\sigma = \sqrt{1/2}$.
if there is a denominator for $\log(x)$ in the exponent, you can choose $\mu=\sigma^2$.

would've made a comment but i can't comment.

[also numerically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnVMq.png), where my distribution is `exp(-log(x)^2) / sqrt(sqrt(ℯ)) / sqrt(π)`

```
using Distributions
using Plots
inspectdr()
lw = 3
f(x) = exp(-log(x)^2) / sqrt(sqrt(ℯ)) / sqrt(π)
p = plot(f, label="my distribution", linestyle=:dot, linewidth=lw*2, size=(1000, 700))
dist = LogNormal(0.5, sqrt(0.5))
p = plot(p, x->pdf(dist, x), label="log normal (0.5, sqrt(0.5)", linestyle=:dash, linewidth=lw)
savefig(p, "fig.png")
p
```

Comment: On the 4th line, you messed up the minus sign. It should be $+\log x$ in the exponent, not $-\log x$.. This would lead to a factor of $x$, not $1/x$. Hence, you don't just get a log-normal distribution.

Comment: yes you do just get log normal, i added some development