# Does the distribution whose pdf is proportional to $\exp(-\log^2(x))$ have a name?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I know that $\dfrac{\exp(-\log^2(x))}{\sqrt[4]{e}\sqrt{\pi}}$
is a valid probability density function on the range $(0, \infty)$ (left inclusive if we assume that it is zero at the limit point 0). The function is positive and has a unit integral.

But does it have a name?

Comment: I don't know a name. Is that the square of $\log$ ? If so it is similar to the density of $e^X$ for $X\sim N(0,1)$ which we call lognormal distribution. That density is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\,x}e^{-(\log^2x)/2}$.

Comment: yes that is the square of the log but it's not divided by $x$. This distribution's mode is one. unlike log normal.

Comment: Basically the same question, though neither has an answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4454097/what-positive-distribution-has-the-form-x-lnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that this is indeed a log normal, just with $\mu=0.5$
\begin{align}
\frac{\exp(-\log^2x)}{\sqrt[4]e\sqrt\pi} 
&= \exp(-\log^2 x - 0.25) / \sqrt{\pi}\\
&= \exp(-(\log^2 x + 0.25 - \log x + \log x)) / \sqrt{\pi}\\
&= \exp(-((\log^2 x - 0.5)^2 + \log x)) / \sqrt{\pi}\\
&= \exp(-(\log^2 x - 0.5)^2 - \log x) / \sqrt{\pi}\\
&= \exp(-(\log x - 0.5)^2) / \sqrt{\pi} / x
\end{align}
This is the probability density function of a  log-normal with $\mu=0.5$ and $\sigma=\sqrt{1/2}$.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: On the 2nd line, you messed up the minus sign. It should be $+\log x$ in the exponent, not $-\log x$.. This would lead to a factor of $x$, not $1/x$. Hence, you don't just get a log-normal distribution.

Comment: it's a log normal, alright, i just messed up the algebra.